# Wave Short Message content

Tags: omnet++, veins

I used veins 4a2 and OMNET++ (4.6). I like to know the content of messages exchanged between vehicles in the veins example.
I have consulted **waveshortmessage.msg**, **WaveShortMessage_m.cc** and **WaveShortMessage_m.h** but I have not found messages content.

In ***waveshortmessage.msg***, what means this line "**string wsmData = "Some Data"**" please?

And in ***TraCIDemp11p.cc***, what means "**blockedRoadId**" declared in sendMessage function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demo application that comes with Veins 4.4 (and 4a2 as well) and that is used for the [Veins tutorial](http://veins.car2x.org/tutorial/) reacts to messages that contain the name of a road to avoid because a car has stopped there for longer than 10s (and vice versa: the demo application sends a message when a car is stopped for longer than 10s).

The demo application is defined in [TraCIDemo11p](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L63). It uses a demo message type, [WaveShortMessage](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-4.4/src/veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage.msg#L45), as the container to inform other cars about a blocked road. For this, it stores the name of the blocked road (variable `blockedRoadId`) in the `wsmData` field of the message.